# Pass parameters to window.open method without appending to url

Tags: window.open

I am currently using window.open() method in the following manner

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Where url is of the form

```
testUrl.com/assist?param1=param1&param2=param2&param3=param3
```

I wanted to pass the information in such a manner that the audience is not able to view the params. Is there any other way in which params can be sent to window.open() method

Comment: need more info. Do you control both sites? Are they the same domain? Do you run the server?

Comment: @gman yes, we are controlling both sites. They are on the same domain

Comment: Well, window.open. returns a window object if they are on the same domain so you can reach directly into the DOM of the window you opened and set things. You can also communicate via postMessage as well as localStorage. [this example](http://greggman.github.io/doodles/webgl_multiple_windows.html) opens windows and communicates. [this example](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-geometry-lathe.html) the diagrams are each an iframe and communicating via localStorage (they'd work as windows as well)